# MySQL: When I restore a mysql dump into a new database, does it matter what the new database is called?

Tags: mysql, database

If I have a dump of a database created with `mysqldump`, which I want to restore into a new database, created empty, does it matter what the new database is called, compared to the old database?

Will there be any issues if I give the new database a different name from the old database which was used to create the dump?

Comment: the dump file is like a SQL script; if delete the SQL "create database if not exists xxxx", you can restore it into a new database with new name; Before restore, remember to execute "use <new database name>";

Comment: Open up the dump file with a text editor - you will see the database name is specified in the first two command lines. You can modify those to be what you want.

Comment: Thanks guys! Accepted the answer below, can't accept comments anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Most of the time it doesn't matter. You are only creating tables and inserting values. As [Green Blade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6138456/green-blade) said, If there is any create database query we should remove those lines and use your database name

```
--
-- Database: `database_name`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `database_name` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `database_name`;
```

instead of above you should use like below.

```
--
-- Database: `database_name`
--

USE `database_name`;
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be on the top of the script? Because I have neither `create` nor `use` there (I seem to have had no need for the `use` statement on other occasions). Then I guess it's ok. The only place where I can find reference to the old name is in some text string which seems to have to do with database migration. `s:80:\"/var/www/2014/assets/wp-migrate-db/[DB_NAME]-migrate-20160402143829-2l3iw.sql.gz\"`. There is a few of there, like 3 - 4 something.

Comment: So there is no problem because of this ` s:80:\"/var/www/201‌​4/assets/wp-migrate-d‌​b/[DB_NAME]-migrate-2‌​0160402143829-2l3iw.s‌​ql.gz\ ` text strings

Comment: Alright, thanks. Accepting this because it is an answer, not a comment :)